# JavaFx does not reach class constructor

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having a strange issue where javaFX isn't reaching my constructor, or any part of my class, there is no console output defining an error. An application titled 'java' opens, but does not respond to any close attempts except by ending the process. JavaFX does work on my computer, as I'm able to run other applications in this environment.

When run through the debugger, it doesn't appear to reach or break on the constructor, so my thought is it never reaches?

A video of the issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=713PRbDKKzU

Here is the MainApp class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    private Doublet doublet = new Doublet();

    public MainApp() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Doublets");
        initRootLayout();
        showGameLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class
                    .getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a `System.out.println(...)` at the beginning of the `start()` method. If it isn't reaching that point, my best bet would be that `new Doublet()` is somehow causing it to block.

Comment: It doesn't reach the println, and after removing Doublet it still does the same thing.

Comment: I figured it out, it wasn't set up as a JavaFX application in Eclipse, so I'm assuming a path probably wasn't set correctly.